# How to use html tags in JTextArea

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextarea, jtextcomponent

When I try to change color of a JTextArea using

```
textArea.setText("<html> <font color=\"red\"> Hi </font></html>")
```

, the text is shown is basically the whole text written inside setText method. But similar things work for JLabel, JButton etc.

How can I do that for a JTextArea also?

Comment: I wouldn't use a JTextArea for this but rather a JEditorPane. It has built in support for HTML.

Comment: No how. Look for another component.

Answer (score 31):

- don't to use `JTextArea` for `Html` formatted `Object` (even is possible, but why bothering)
- use `JTextPane` / `JEditorPane` instead ([setContentType("text/html")](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#setContentType%28java.lang.String%29))
- notice, todays Java and methods implemented in `Official API by Oracle` supporting only reduced `Html syntax with css <= Html 3.2`
- use `JavaFX` in the case that you want/need to use todays `Html5`,

Comment: JTextPane with setContenType("text/html") seems to the option with fewest dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

JavaFX WebView is very powerful for rendering HTML and You can easily display javafx component(WebView) in your Swing Application by using JFXPanel. For tutorial of embedding fx in swing here is one from oracle: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/swing-fx-interoperability.htm

Thanks