# Using HTML on java string variables

Tags: java, html, string

I'm right now working on a simple chat program, and I came up with an issue I couldn't find anywhere in the web, maybe because I didn't use the correct words to describe it.

So, I want to simply color part of a text I'm appending to a JTextArea using html, but the problem is the part of the text I want to color is stored in a String variable, and I don't know how to apply the html on it.

this is  what I'm trying to do in code:

```
String text = new String("Hello");
String htmlText = new String("<html><font color='red'>" + text + "</font></html>");
```

But the output is `<html><font color='red'>Hello</font></html>`

Thanks, and sorry for my bad English.

**Edit**

I have solved the problem.
It was because my `textPane.setText()` method was
`("<html>"+textPane.getText+"<font color='red'>text</font></html>)`

I shouldn't have used `textPane.getText()`, I should have used `textPane.getDocument().getText(0, text.getDocument().getLength())`.

my present code is:

```
//chatArea is a JTextPane
//mesArea is just a source where I get some text
if (!mesArea.getText().trim().equals("")) {
    mesArea.setText(mesArea.getText().trim());
    try {
        if (chatArea.getDocument().getText(0, chatArea.getDocument().getLength()).equals("")) {
            chatArea.setText("<html><font color='green'>"+user.getNickname()+": </font>"+mesArea.getText()+"</html>");

        } else {
            System.out.println("what");
            String paneText = new String(chatArea.getDocument().getText(0, chatArea.getDocument().getLength()));
            chatArea.setText("<html>"+paneText+"\n<font color='green'>"+user.getNickname()+": </font>"+mesArea.getText()+"</html>");
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    mesArea.setText("");
} else {
    mesArea.setText("");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use html tags in JTextArea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195131/how-to-use-html-tags-in-jtextarea)

Comment: If this is the observed output [ <html><font color='red'>Hello</font></html> ] can you please describe how your expected output would look like?.

Comment: @Tom I tried what they said, but now it just prints out nothing!

Comment: @Pavan What I expect is the word hello in red, and if there was more text (after the </font>) ),then I still want only the word hello in red.

Comment: @IdoFangBentov If you tried the answers from the linked question and they didn't work for you, then please update your question and post your current code and your current results. Please read this [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to know how to format code correctly.

Comment: @Tom I'm sorry I haven't replied for a long time, I wasn't near my computer... I will edit the post soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `JTextPane / JEditorPane` instead of JTextArea 
like

```
String text = new String("Hello");
String htmlText = new String("<html><font color='red'>" + text + "</font></html>");
JTextPane jTextPane =new JTextPane ();
jTextPane.setContentType("text/html");
jTextPane.setText(htmlText);
```